# Git putting folders in folders - In a repository

Tags: git, github, repository, directory

So, I'm pretty  new to the whole GitHub thing. Consequently my repo looks like a messy pile of shit.
Anyway, I wanted to put in a little effort to clear it up, so I pulled it down, updated the folder system to how I wanted it, and pushed it back up.
Anyway, the new folders are showing there with the sub-folders inside. However, the sub-folders are still showing in my repository. I would rather they were in these folders so I can keep it a bit better organised. Is there anyway to do this and would someone mind walking me through it?

Cheers for the help in advance. :)

Comment: _Anyway, the new folders are showing there with the sub-folders inside. However, the sub-folders are still showing in my repository_ Can you specify if the you are talking about is a local or remote(on github site) repo?

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to understand a little. 

I have the repository online, it's a private repo. 
I cloned it onto a computer a Uni, fixed it up, re-uploaded. The new folders were added and they contain the sub-folders.
However, the sub-folders were left in my main window alongside the new folders.

On the repo I cloned onto the computer, I modified it so that it was just the two folders, then the rest of the stuff inside. Folders within folders, then my files within the sub-folders.

Comment: Did you commit the changes? and pushed it using following: `git add .` adds the changes to index. Then commit with `git commit -m <ur commit msg>` then do `git push origin master` to push the changes to remote repo.

Comment: Yes sir, I did this and it all uploaded, so I can see the work on the page. 
I made sure to go back to my local repository, I reordered all the folders, then I added, committed, and pushed again.

Then when I go and look at my remote repo, my main folders are all displayed in the repo section, as are the parent folders I placed them in. If I enter the parent folders, I can view my main folders and access my work inside them. I've triple checked my local repo, made sure I was uploading correctly, and it all seems to be working. I made some other modifications and pushed them, but it still hasn'

Comment: fixed my folder structure.
(Sorry if I'm not too helpful on explaining this.)

Comment: Ok the easiest trick would be since you have good local repo. Just delete the remote one, create new remote repo with same name as local & push the changes.

Comment: Thanks a butt-load dude!
Works flawlessly now. :)

Comment: Great!! accept your answer as an answer. :) So others will know that your issue was resolved. Cheers!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Question is explained above by @Healsgood.

**The easiest solution:**

Since the local repo is in the desired form and also latest with additional changes. First delete the remote repo(current), create a new remote repo with the same name as in local and **push**(`git push`) the changes to remote. You will have same/desired version of remote repo.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Still learning SOF. Figured this would close my question as it has been solved with the thanks of uDaY.

Original Issue: Folder directory in my remote repo was different to my local repo. Pushing would not update this correctly.

Solution: In the end I deleted my remote repo and repushed my local repo. This corrected the folder directory to that of my local repo and solved the issue. My repo is now nice and pretty, thank you uDaY.

Comment: Great! Accept it as answer. So others will know that your issue is resolved. :)

Comment: I have to wait two days before I can choose mine, unfortunately. If you write it up then throw an answer I can choose that as the answer.

:)