# Can Git merge "use" the information found by git blame -C

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-merge

This question came to me after reading this one : [Can Git really track the movement of a single function from 1 file to another? If so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908336/can-git-really-track-the-movement-of-a-single-function-from-1-file-to-another-i)

Here is the worfklow :

A "long time ago", we splitted a big file `folder/file.py` in many files : `folder1/file.py`, `folder2/file.py` and so on.

`git blame -C` shows correctly the history of that code when we look at `folder2/file.py`, we see that some of the commits were made before this splitting.

The problem is that we continue to maintain old versions of the code that still have `folder/file.py` and when we merge the fixes back in the "current" version, git keeps re-creating the folder `folder` and does not see that a fix made to `folder/file.py` should be merged into `folder1/file.py` OR `folder2/file.py` depending on where this chunk of code is now located.

I look rapidly at `git help merge` but did not find anything about that.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005813/git-putting-folders-in-folders-in-a-repository/11010454#11010454

Answer (score 0):

Merges cannot leverage `git blame -C`, but `git merge` does have rename detection. From the man page:

```
   rename-threshold=<n>
   Controls the similarity threshold used for rename detection. See also git-diff(1) -M.
```

Git's rename threshold is likely too high to detect your renames during merge. It's also possible the [detection is too computationally intense.](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/195197/focus=195292) Try conducting a test merge with a lower rename-threshold, say 75:

```
git merge -X rename-threshold=75 <branch>
```

You might have to play around for a while to find the right number, and if git quits because it's too computationally difficult, try setting the `git config merge.renamelimit 0` discussed in the thread linked above.

[This answer might also help if the above fails.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5487775/877115) I haven't tried `-X ignore-space-change` or the linked script, but it might be worth investigation.